# $.ajax callback inside class undefined – scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gracenote

I'm trying to return a list of movie showtimes playing in a given radius. I have a JavaScript class that I'm building to display the data from an API. I actually followed the example given from [here](http://developer.tmsapi.com/Sample_Code). I know this is a scoping issue of some kind, because if I move my callback function (dataHandler) outside of the class then it works fine.

Here is my class (dumbed down) – If I run this code as it is here I'm getting a reference error, "dataHander is undefined".

Thanks in advance! Hope there's enough info here to help..

```
function Locator() {
    // Init
    function init(){
        test();
    };


    function test() {
        // construct the url with parameter values
        var apikey = "myapikey";
        var baseUrl = "http://data.tmsapi.com/v1";
        var showtimesUrl = baseUrl + '/movies/showings';
        var zipCode = "78701";
        var d = new Date();
        var today = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate();

        // send off the query
        $.ajax({
            url: showtimesUrl,
            data: { startDate: today,
                zip: zipCode,
                api_key: apikey,
                jsonp: "dataHandler"
            },
            dataType: "jsonp",
        });

        // callback to handle the results
        function dataHandler(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    };

    init();
    // Return
    return {

    };
};
```

Comment: You can remove a lot of unnecessary semicolons after the closing brace for a function (e.g. after the `init` function), but more importantly, are you running this code on `document.ready`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Much appreciated. This an instance of this class is being created on document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is how you are handling the jsonp callback.

You are passing the jsonp callback using a parameter named `jsonp` and is passing a function name `dataHandler` but the function `dataHandler` is a closure method inside the method `test`. When the response comes back the method named `dataHandler` will be searched in the global context where it does not exists thus causing the error.

You can use the ajax handler `success` to process the returned data like

```
// send off the query
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
        startDate: '',
        zip: '',
        api_key: ''
    },
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/95w826L5/1/)

Comment: This does exactly what I need it to do, thanks! Now I'm assuming I can save the data into a variable to use elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) code to the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: showtimesUrl,
    data: {
        startDate: today,
        zip: zipCode,
        api_key: apikey
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "jsonp"
}).done(dataHandler);
```

This is based on the [v1 API documentation for OnConnect](http://developer.tmsapi.com/docs/data_v1/).